# How to include pdb information from another library in my library in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, linker, static-libraries

My solution includes my main project(A) and a library(B) that i made for this project. My library(B) uses another library(C) as a dependency. Libraries (B) and (C) are compiled with `/7Z` format meaning it should include `pdb` info in its own `.lib` file. However, Visual studio keep giving me `Link4099` warning saying it didn't find library(C) `pdb` file from library(B) in the project (A).

How can i include Library(C)'s `pdb` file in library(B).

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer as static libraries don't normally combine into each other. Instead you link your application or dll to each static library needed.

Comment: But if I link my project(A) to library(C) directly, can i still use library (C) in library (B)?